# Why is Azure CLI reporting ResourceGroupNotFound when trying to run New-AzResourceGroupDeployment?

Tags: azure, azure-cli, azure-cloud-shell

I'm trying to create an Application Insights resource following the directions provided here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/powershell

However, when I execute the command from the docs:

```
New-AzResourceGroupDeployment -ResourceGroupName Fabrikam -TemplateFile .\template1.json -appName myNewApp
```

Replacing Fabrikam my Resource Group Name, it throws ResourceGroupNotFound. If I list the Resource Groups with:

```
az group list
```

I can clearly see the Resource Group in the list, so I know I'm in the right subscription context.

Any thing obvious that I'm missing?

I've uploaded my version of template1.json already to the CLI storage.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I can clearly see the Resource Group in the list, so I know I'm in the right subscription context.

No, if you can use `az group list` to see the group, it just means the azure CLI context is in the right subscription. The `New-AzResourceGroupDeployment` is azure powershell, they are different, you need to use `Get-AzResourceGroup` to list groups.

To check if you are in the correct subscription, just use `Get-AzContext`. If you want to set the subscription for the powershell context, just use `Set-AzContext -Subscription "<subscription-id>"`.

> I've uploaded my version of template1.json already to the CLI storage.

I suppose you mean you upload the template to the azure storage. If so, you could not use this parameter `-TemplateFile`, you need to use `-TemplateUri` and `-TemplateParameterUri`, you need to generate the SAS urls for your template files(if your container is not public), then specify the two parameters, see this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-template-deploy).

---

Actually, you can use `New-AzResource` to create the app insight directly, no need to use the template in the doc.

**Sample**:

```
New-AzResource -ResourceName "<appinsight-name>" -ResourceGroupName <resourcegroup-name> -ResourceType "Microsoft.Insights/components" -Location "East US" -PropertyObject @{"Application_Type"="web"}
```

[image]

Comment: The first part of your answer got me on the right path. Once I set Context explicitly it found the resource group. I didn't need to change TemplateFile to TemplateUri it worked as is, presumably because in this case it acts like a file structure.